# Why can't I instantiate an empty array of a nested class?

Tags: swift

I seem to be having problems instantiating an empty array of a nested class type using the `[foo]()` style syntax:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

class outsideClass {

}

class Wrapper {
    class InsideClass {
    }
}

var foo = [outsideClass]() // Works fine

// Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[Wrapper.InsideClass.Type]'
var bar = [Wrapper.InsideClass]()
```

Is this something I'm misunderstanding—it's before my coffee, but I've checked the release notes, and I think you should be able to refer to nested classes like this—or a bug in beta 7?

This works fine as a workaround:

```
var foobar: [Wrapper.InsideClass] = []
```

Comment: There are other cases where the `[type]()` syntax does not work, e.g. with tuples. Send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Confidence suitably bolstered by your comment and a cup of coffee, I will do that, and answer the question, too.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug in the compiler, especially as you're *allowed* to instantiate an empty array of a nested class just fine; it simply doesn't work with the initialiser syntax.

I'll raise a bug. In the meantime, for anyone experiencing the problem, you can work around it by using assignment syntax with an empty array and a specified class for the variable, rather than constructor syntax:

```
 var foobar: [Wrapper.InsideClass] = []
```

Comment: Is it still a thing on the verge of 2016?

Comment: @dVaffection All I can tell you is that my bug was closed as a duplicate of [another, which is still open](http://openradar.appspot.com/19812302).

Comment: It is still a bug as today, the workaround works fine

Comment: It's still a bug in Xcode 7.3.1 (Swift 2.2) released a couple of days ago.

Comment: It's still a bug in Swift 3.

Comment: Its still there as of today.

Comment: I could not test it yet, but according to the Xcode 9.1 release notes, this has been fixed.

Comment: @MartinR I wonder if it was fixed on the exact three-year anniversary of this post :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do is to use `Array<T>()` constructor.

```
let arrayOfNestedClass = Array<Wrapper.InsideClass>()
```