# swift - create empty string : tuple dictionary using literal

Tags: dictionary, swift, tuples, literals

can anyone explain why line 1 works to create an empty swift dictionary but line 2 doesn't when i try to create a swift dictionary with int key and tuple of double values .... how should it be done?

```
var testDic2 = [Int:Double]()

var testDic3 = [Int:(Double,Double)]()
```

I've tried various combinations in playgrounds and the only version where it doesnt give me a compiler error is as follows

```
    var possibleTips = [Int(): (tipAmt:Double(), total:Double())]
```

but im not sure this last form is declaring the dictionary as i intend it (ie as per testDict3 above)

Comment: Can't reproduce any error based on what you've said. Voting to close on that basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler isn't sure how to instantiate the type in your second and third example. Instead, you can declare the type and use an empty dictionary initializer:

```
var testDic:[Int:(Double,Double)] = [:]
```

Comment: [I had to use this kind of workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682113/why-cant-i-instantiate-an-empty-array-of-a-nested-class/25683424#25683424) to get an array of nested class instances, too. That also didn't work with the initialiser syntax. I'd probably report this as a compiler bug; I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I saw a radar a while back, not sure what the status on that is - but I've seen it happen sometimes and sometimes work so I assume it's indeed a bug. Additionally I see people with this issue at #swift-lang every now and then. This fix is the shortest we came up with and it works consistently. Hopefully in the future it won't be needed.