# Why can't I use the short Array constructor syntax when creating an Array of a nested Struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Consider a struct nested inside another struct:

```
struct Struct1 {
    struct Struct2 {
        var name: String?
    }
}
```

I want to create an array of `Struct2` values.  At first I tried:

```
var struct2Array = [Struct1.Struct2]()
```

But this gives the compiler error:

> ```
> error: invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[Struct1.Struct2.Type]'
> var struct2Array = [Struct1.Struct2]()
> ```

I can create an array by declaring the type of the variable and using an empty array, or with the more verbose syntax:

```
var struct2Array: [Struct1.Struct2] = []
var struct2ArrayVerbose = Array<Struct1.Struct2>()
```

But why can't I use the shorthand initializer for a nested Struct?

Comment: Another one here: [Why can't I instantiate an empty array of a nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682113/why-cant-i-instantiate-an-empty-array-of-a-nested-class).

Comment: @MartinR ah, guess I should have searched for nested types in general.  I though this was just an issue with structs.  Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR Nice one. Now that we have bugs.swift.org, he should still file a bug; it's a lot more responsive.

Comment: Sometimes I have the feeling that I spend more time hunting for duplicates than answering ... :)  – In this case a search for `[swift] nested type array` was immediately successful.

Comment: Opened a ticket on Swift.org https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2428

Comment: @MartinR I know the feeling.  Guess I should have searched better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a hole in the language. After all, the `[Type]` syntax is just syntactic sugar; as you rightly say, if you use the real syntax with `Array<Type>`, or use `[Type]` but not as a constructor, there's no problem. You can also work around it with type alias:

```
struct Struct1 {
    struct Struct2 {
        var name: String?
    }
}

typealias Struct2 = Struct1.Struct2

var struct2Array = [Struct2]()
```

Comment: And file a bug with bugs.swift.org.

Comment: Thanks matt!  I was just about to ask if I should file a ticket on the Swift Jira board.  On it now.  Thanks again!