# Swift 3.0 - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when initializing dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I get this error on Xcode 8:

*Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*

When trying to initialize a Dictionary where the key is a String and the value is an enum of a custom struct, here is the line that generates the error:

```
var myDictionary = [String: MyStruct.MyEnum]()
```

and here is the class, is contained in the same file of the line above, so I think it's not a problem of scope:

```
fileprivate struct MyStruct {
    fileprivate enum MyEnum {
        case enumValue1
        case enumValue2
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Potentially related? [Why can't I use the short Array constructor syntax when creating an Array of a nested Struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041712/why-cant-i-use-the-short-array-constructor-syntax-when-creating-an-array-of-a-n)

Comment: I think the issue in the question above is the same, try using a typealias.

Comment: A typealias solved...thanks!!