# Weird escaping function behavior after updating to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm having difficulties with the following lines of code after updating to Swift 3:

```
private var functionHandlers = [(() -> Int) -> ()]()

private var myFunction: (() -> Int)?

func doRegister() {
    functionHandlers.append { (f: (() -> Int)) in
        myFunction = f
    }
}
```

That gave me the compiler error: `Assigning non-escaping parameter 'f' to an escaping closure`

So then, I tried this:

```
func doRegister() {
    functionHandlers.append { (f: @escaping (() -> Int)) in
        myFunction = f
    }
}
```

and this:

```
func doRegister() {
    functionHandlers.append { (f: (@escaping () -> Int)) in
        myFunction = f
    }
}
```

which, in both cases, fixed my first error, but then gave me a new compiler error: `Cannot convert value of type '(@escaping (() -> Int)) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> Int) -> ()'`

So then I tried changing the type of `functionHandlers` as follows:

```
private var functionHandlers = [(@escaping (() -> Int)) -> ()]()
```

but that just resulted in a syntax error.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Where does the `.append { }` trailing closure come from?

Comment: He's appending a function @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: I think the @escaping needs to be one paren over: [((@escaping () -> Int)) -> ()]()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. For some reason, the compiler doesn't like the syntax:

```
private var functionHandlers = [(@escaping () -> Int) -> ()]()
```

but it does like:

```
private var functionHandlers : [(@escaping () -> Int) -> ()] = []
```

It's the same symptom, but I'm unsure it's the same cause as [the compiler rejecting the `[TypeA.TypeB]()` syntax with nested types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682113/why-cant-i-instantiate-an-empty-array-of-a-nested-class). Although like that problem, another way of solving it is by using a `typealias`:

```
typealias F = (@escaping () -> Int) -> ()

private var functionHandlers = [F]()
```

You can then implement `doRegister()` as you correctly tried to implement it as:

```
func doRegister() {
    functionHandlers.append { (f: @escaping () -> Int) in
        myFunction = f
    }
}
```

Although you should certainly [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org) over `[(@escaping () -> Int) -> ()]()` not compiling.

Comment: I've seen the same issue (and worked around it with typealias).