# Swift Dictionary Initialization of custom type gives: '>' is not a postfix unary operator error

Tags: swift

I am trying to initialise a empty dictionary with custom type in Swift but I am getting `'>' is not a postfix unary operator error`

```
struct Prims {
    var msSet = [Vertex<Int> : Double]() // This lines gives error
}
```

I tried another way; still getting same error

```
struct Prims {
  var msSet: [Vertex<Int> : Double]

   init() {
    self.msSet = [Vertex<Int> : Double]()
   }
}
```

I have defined Vertex in separate file

```
import Foundation

public struct Vertex<T: Hashable> {
    var data: T
}

extension Vertex: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(data)".hashValue
    }

    static public func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
}

extension Vertex: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "\(data)"
    }
}
```

I am looking for `Why` it is happening. I know using `var msSet = Dictionary<Vertex<Int>, Double>()` will work.

Comment: There have been a few bugs surrounding the syntactic sugar form of the array initialiser – compare [Weird escaping function behavior after updating to Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40599881/2976878) & [Why can't I use the short Array constructor syntax when creating an Array of a nested Struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39041712/2976878). I would say this is just another variant of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't tell you why the swift compiler emits this error, you can make it compile like this:

```
struct Prims {
    var msSet = Dictionary<Vertex<Int>, Double>()
}
```

or like this:

```
struct Prims {
    typealias V = Vertex<Int>
    var msSet = [V : Double]()
}
```

Comment: I am looking for `Why`?

Comment: Sure sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried reporting it?

Comment: Thanks for the accept and the upvote. Have you ever gotten around to filing a bug or found a duplicate? I just tried to compile your code using swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2017-05-12-a.xctoolchain and the error is still there.

Comment: you are welcome. It is just a syntactic sugar and I read that it will be added later on and so didn't file a bug for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of going about this:

```
msSet = Dictionary< Vertex<Int>, Double >()
```

or

```
mSet = [ (Vertex<Int>), Double ]()
```

or even more verbose

```
typealias VertexInt=Vertex<Int>
mSet = [ VertexInt, Double ]
```

I looked over the swift grammar and couldn't find an answer as to why that particular syntax is not valid. It may very well be a bug.

Comment: Thanks @Radu but I am looking for `Why?`

Comment: Most likely a bug in the compiler

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Prims {
    var msSet = [Vertex<Int> : Double]() // This lines gives error
}
```

change to

```
struct Prims {
    var msSet = [(Vertex<Int>) : Double]() // This lines gives error
}
```

complete code

```
struct Prims {
    var msSet = [(Vertex<Int>) : Double]()
}

public struct Vertex<T: Hashable> {
    var data: T
}

extension Vertex: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return data.hashValue
    }

    static public func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
}

extension Vertex: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "\(data)"
    }
}
```

test Code

```
var test = Prims()
test.msSet.updateValue(43, forKey: Vertex(data: 12))
```