# What is the difference between Dictionary<String, Any?> and [String:Any?]

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to pass an optional dictionary parameter in Swift function, I tried declaring the function as

```
 func myFunction(_ type:Int, params:Dictionary<String,Any?>?)
```

and also

```
 func myFunc(_ type:Int, params:[String:Any?]?)
```

I get warning "Expression implicitly coerced from Any? to Any" with first declaration when I try to pass a dictionary but not with second. I need to know what is the difference between the two and why the warning. FYI, here is how I pass the dictionary in both cases:

```
myFunc(1, params:["key1": value1, "key2": value2])
```

Comment: `["key1", value1, "key2", value2]` is array not dictionary

Comment: You should avoid using dictionary types with optional values, as the `Dictionary` API uses `nil` to indicate the lack of key for a given value. Having an optional `Value` type therefore will give you double-wrapped optionals, which can cause all sorts confusion.

Comment: But in any case, please provide us with a [mcve]. The code you've shown us is both incomplete (what's `value1` and `value2`?) and incorrect in places – you're trying to pass an array literal into a dictionary parameter, you're missing off the closing `)` on your function call, your two functions have different names (`myFunc` vs. `myFunction`).

Comment: @NiravD Sorry for the typo, I made the correction and now it is correct!

Answer (score 1):

According to Swift documentation, they are identical:

> The type of a Swift dictionary is written in full as Dictionary<Key,
>   Value>, where Key is the type of value that can be used as a
>   dictionary key, and Value is the type of value that the dictionary
>   stores for those keys.
>
> You can also write the type of a dictionary in shorthand form as [Key:
>   Value]. Although the two forms are functionally identical, the
>   shorthand form is preferred and is used throughout this guide when
>   referring to the type of a dictionary.

I'm using Xcode Version 8.0 and i couldn't regenerate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

They are just different syntactic sugar for dictionary declaration and one type will not work in all cases which are kind of a bug.

For Example,

```
  var msSet = [Vertex<Int> : Double]()
```

I have asked a question related to it.

[Swift Dictionary Initialization of custom type gives: '>' is not a postfix unary operator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272342/swift-dictionary-initialization-of-custom-type-gives-is-not-a-postfix-unary)