# How to use enum (which is defined inside a struct) as key of dictionary?

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
struct TestStruct2 {
    let field1: String
    let field2: Int

    enum TestEnum2 {
        case Value1
        case Value2
    }

}

    let dic2 = Dictionary<TestStruct2.TestEnum2, TestStruct2>()
    let dic3 = [TestStruct2.TestEnum2 : TestStruct2]()
```

dic2 works successfully.

But dic3 returns an compiler error:

```
 (Type of expression is ambiguous without more context)
```

I don't understand why. Any Ideas?

Comment: This is a compiler bug, see [Why can't I instantiate an empty array of a nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682113/why-cant-i-instantiate-an-empty-array-of-a-nested-class) You can also use a `typealias` of the nested type to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Hamish in the comments, this is a compiler bug.  You've already shown one workaround which is to use the long form:

```
let dic2 = Dictionary<TestStruct2.TestEnum2, TestStruct2>()
```

A second workaround is to create a `typealias` for the nested type:

```
typealias TestStruct2Enum2 = TestStruct2.TestEnum2

let dic3 = [TestStruct2Enum2 : TestStruct2]()
```

A third workaround is to create a `typealias` of the entire dictionary:

```
typealias Test2Dict = [TestStruct2.TestEnum2 : TestStruct2]

let dic4 = Test2Dict()
```

A fourth workaround is to explicitly specify the type and initialize the dictionary with the `[:]` literal:

```
let dic5: [TestStruct2.TestEnum2 : TestStruct2] = [:]
```

A final workaround is to cast the literal to the type:

```
let dic6 = [:] as [TestStruct2.TestEnum2 : TestStruct2]
```