# Can't use nested hashable type as key in dictionary get "type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, dictionary, types

Another "type of expression is ambiguous" question. I don't think anyone's raised this exact situation so far...

If I embed a class within another class, and make it `Hashable`, it seems I can't use it as a key:

```
class TestClassWithKey {
    class Key: Hashable {
        static func == (left: Key, right: Key) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
        var hashValue: Int {
            return 4
        }
    }
}
var myList = [TestClassWithKey.Key: TestClassWithKey]()
// Above line gives classic "type of expression is ambiguous"
// compiler error.
```

Obviously ridiculous example, but if I do the same but without the nesting, everything is hunky dory:

```
class TestClassWithoutKeyKey: Hashable {
    static func == (left: TestClassWithoutKeyKey, right: TestClassWithoutKeyKey) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
        return 4
    }
}
class TestClassWithoutKey {
}
var myList = [TestClassWithoutKeyKey: TestClassWithoutKey]()
```

I would like to know if there is some way I can use a nested type as the key to a dictionary, or (ideally) if not why not.

On swift 3, but I don't think that's relevant...

Comment: This is the same issue as [Why can't I instantiate an empty array of a nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682113/why-cant-i-instantiate-an-empty-array-of-a-nested-class) – you can either say `var myList : [TestClassWithKey.Key : TestClassWithKey] = [:]`, or refer to the type without the syntactic sugar, or use a `typealias`.

Comment: Dammit, thanks, I blame swift's plethora of container types for me not finding it!