# Why does a typealias make my expression unambiguous?

Tags: swift

In the code below, when I reference `C.ID` directly instead of using the `ID` typealias, then I get an error, "type of expression is ambiguous without more context". Why does that make it ambiguous if they both refer to the same type?

Using `typealias` is not a terribly inconvenient workaround, but I do find the error confusing.

```
protocol OID: Hashable
{
  var sha: String { get }
}

extension OID { public var hashValue: Int { return sha.hashValue } }

protocol CommitType
{
  associatedtype ID: OID
}

class CommitEntry<C: CommitType>
{
  typealias ID = C.ID

  var lines1 = [ID: (a: UInt, b: UInt)]()    // No problem
  var lines2 = [C.ID: (a: UInt, b: UInt)]()  // Error: ambiguous
}
```

Comment: Probably the same reason as [Why can't I instantiate an empty array of a nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25682113/2976878) – another solution would be `var lines : [C.ID: (a: UInt, b: UInt)] = [:]`

Comment: So it's a compiler bug? I like your alternative. I thought of doing that but didn't try it at first because I assumed it would have the same problem. Turns out it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html):

> An associated type gives a placeholder name to a type that is used as part of the protocol. The actual type to use for that associated type is not specified until the protocol is adopted.

Without specifying the typealias in your class, the compiler has no idea what `ID` is. Thus, you need to tell it what you want `ID` to be using `typealias` 
You can also tell the compiler using type inference:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype ItemType
    subscript(i: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
        return items[i]
    }
}
```

This works because the compiler can infer that `ItemType` has to be an `Int` in this case. For more on this, see the linked [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

Comment: What I'm saying is that in the `var lines` declaration, if I change `ID` to `C.ID` (no longer using the alias, but still referring to the same type) then the compiler says it's ambiguous.